# Best practice to flatten JSON object and store it database

Tags: database, api, mysql, json

I'm fetching data from Clockify, flattening the JSON response, and storing it in the database where each property on the API response should have its own table's field.

I have read [this](https://support.etlworks.com/hc/en-us/articles/360013740973-About-nested-datasets) article about how can I achieve what I'm trying to do, however in my JSON response I have `tagsIds` which looks like an array, and I'm looking for the best way to store them in the database.

I think I can give `tagIds` to DB column name, and store the tags separated by a comma. Is it a good practice or should I store them another way?

```
[
{
    "id": "5fd1c9dfb9189912e857bc7b",
    "description": "",
    "tagIds": [
        "5fd1c9ebb54ab12970cf0f20",
        "5fd1c9f2b54ab12970cf0f5b"
    ],
    "userId": "5fd1c922b9189912e857b563",
    "billable": true,
    "taskId": null,
    "projectId": "5fd1c9d7b9189912e857bc1e",
    "timeInterval": {
        "start": "2020-12-10T07:10:22Z",
        "end": "2020-12-10T07:10:46Z",
        "duration": "PT24S"
    },
    "workspaceId": "5fd1c923b9189912e857b566",
    "isLocked": false,
    "customFieldValues": null
}]
```

Comment: check out this Answers:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098797/fastest-way-to-flatten-un-flatten-nested-json-objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store it as comma-separated list is discouraged because

- hard to ensure data type for each element, e.g, `5fd1c9ebb54ab12970cf0f20,false, 5fd1c9f2b54ab12970cf0f5b`
- hard to guarantee the uniqueness of elements in the list
- may fail to store many tags since it could be longer than the string column
- hard to do query, join, and count operations on the list

You can store each tagId as one row in a separate table instead, with a primary key of (`id`, `tagId`):

```
+-------------+------------------------+----------------
|            id             |        tagId             |
+-------------+------------------------+---------------|
|  5fd1c9dfb9189912e857bc7b | 5fd1c9ebb54ab12970cf0f20 |
|  5fd1c9dfb9189912e857bc7b | 5fd1c9f2b54ab12970cf0f5b |
```

Other than that, worth looking at [JSON_TABLE in mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html), and [Arrays type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html) support in Postgres.